# Calling pointer-to-member function C++

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have a pointer to a member function defined within a class, e.g.:

```
class Example {
   void (Example::*foo)();

   void foo2();
};
```

In my main code, I then set foo as:

```
Example *a;
a->foo = &Example::foo2;
```

However, when I try to call foo:

```
a->foo();
```

I get the following compile time error: "error: expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type". I'm assuming I'm getting the syntax wrong somewhere, can someone point it out to me?

Comment: `(a->*(a->foo))()` - I think?

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. a->*foo() returns "error: foo is undefined" and a->*(a->foo)() gives the original error message.

Comment: you need parens around `a->*(a->foo)` because of how operator precedence works

Comment: you don't have to worry about the strange syntax if you bind the member function to something like `std::function`, but you will pay slightly for the overhead of the indirection doing that.

Comment: Check out the C++ FAQ: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/pointers-to-members.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

to call it you would do: `(a->*(a->foo))()`

`(a->*X)(...)` - dereferences a member function pointer - the parens around `a->*X` are important for precedence.

`X = a->foo` - in your example.

See ideone [here](http://ideone.com/mw2oPC) for working example

Comment: See the C++ FAQ for a working example and discussion: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/pointers-to-members.html