# Calling class member function (of class B) thru the class A function pointer in VC++

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

Let me explain my question thru an example (VC++ code using VS2013).

```
void Imhere(int num)
{
    printf_s("\n Hello World printed %d\n",num);
}
class Abc;
class Dllclas
{
    public:
    void dllFunc()
    {
        printf_s("\n Heelo this is DLl func\n");
    }
};

void outsideFunc()
{
    printf_s("\n Heelo this is outside func\n");
}
typedef void(*outsideFP)();
typedef void (Dllclas::*funcFP)();
class Abc
{
public:
    funcFP fp;
    outsideFP outFp;
    int a;
    void assignOUTFp()
    {
        outFp = &outsideFunc;
    }
    void assignFP()
    {
        fp = &(Dllclas::dllFunc);
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    Abc* abcObj1 = new Abc();
    abcObj1->a = 7;

    abcObj1->assignOUTFp(); 
    abcObj1->outFp();  // THIS FUNCTION CALL WORKS PERFECTLY FINE.

    abcObj1->assignFP();
    abcObj1->fp(); // COMPILATION ERROR.
```

IN this code snippet, in the last line

> abcObj1->fp(); // COMPILATION ERROR.

I'm getting compilation error.

> error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments

Also if I hover my mouse over the "abcObj1->fp()", I get a red error which reads "

> expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have
>   (pointer-to-) function type

Here I'm able to call teh function "abcObj1->outFp(); which is outside any class.
Hence, I know the reason why I'm getting this error is because, teh function address present in "abcObj1->fp();" belongs to a class member function i.e. "dllFunc() of Dllclas class.

I also refered to the link 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686456/calling-pointer-to-member-function-c) but I couldn't resolve the compilation error.

CAn I please get help with code sample?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot find `FP` member. Did you mean `fp`?

Comment: Yes, it's "fp" and not "FP" (typo), I'm sorry. Corrected it just now. Thanks.

Comment: `fp` is a pointer to member of `Dllclas`. You need an instance of `Dllclas` on which to call that member - just as you can't just call `dllFunc` directly without a `Dllclas` instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error can be fixed by removing parentheses:

```
fp = &Dllclas::dllFunc; // This will compile
```

The second problem is harder to fix: recall that in order to call a member function you need two things:

- A pointer to the function, and
- An object on which you call the function.

Therefore, you need a "target" object of type `Dllclas` as well:

```
Dllclas target;
(target.*abcObj1->fp)();
```

The syntax is a bit crazy here - `.*` applies the function pointer obtained through `abcObj1->fp` to the target of invocation, i.e. an object of type `Dllclas`. If you have a pointer to target instead of a target itself, use `->*` operator:

```
Dllclas *targetPtr;
(targetPtr->*abcObj1->fp)();
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for calling a member function pointer `f` if `x` is a pointer is

```
(x->*f)();
```

Since the name of your member pointer (in `_tmain`) is `abcObj->fp`, you need to use

```
(abcObj->*(abcObj->fp))();
```

You can simplify by adding another member to `Abc`, like

```
void callFP()
{
   (*fp)();
}
```